# Snakemake DAG not working because of literal dot being encountered - possible Graphiz dot issue?

Tags: graphviz, dot, snakemake

I am trying to use the `snakemake --dag` or `snakemake --rulegraph` piped to  `dot` but I end up getting errors because I assume graphviz is not able to handle the literal dot '.'

I am using snakemake 5.4.5 in a conda environment in linux.

I end up getting errors that keep saying "syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number" and I believe it is more of a graphviz issue than snakemake.

Has anybody else in the snakemake community experienced something like this and come up with a workaround?

Thanks in advance.

I happened to see something similar listed here - https://github.com/influxdata/kapacitor/issues/1068

`snakemake --forceall --rulegraph | dot -Tpdf > dag.pdf`

Error messages

Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '.11.' in line 1 of  splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '.11.' in line 3 of  splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '0.13.' in line 4 of  splits into two tokens
Warning: syntax ambiguity - badly delimited number '3.5.' in line 6 of  splits into two tokens
Building DAG of jobs...

Comment: You may want to write a ticket in [their repo](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/src/master/) describing your issue.

Comment: Thanks @JeeYem.  I have used your suggestion and posted my question as a ticket on the snakemake repo. Here is a link to the ticket:https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1195/snakemake-dag-not-working-because-of